# Should I still use the <b> tag?

Tags: html, web-development, standards

A while ago I learned to use proper CSS stylesheets on my websites. However, on Wikipedia and eBay and other sites I see the deprecated `<b><i>` tags being used. I was going for `<span style="font-weight:bold;"></span>` but I ***never*** see it done that way.

So what's up with the WC3 standards. Are `<b>` tags back in style?

Comment: FYI the word is **deprecated**, not **depreciated**. The latter means to decrease in value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Su is correct, but to address @Konrad's comment - W3.org (home of the W3C) [answers this question directly](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags)

> The HTML5 specification redefines b and i elements to have some
>   semantic function, rather than being purely presentational. However,
>   the simple fact that the tag names are 'b' for bold and 'i' for italic
>   means that people are likely to continue using them as a quick
>   presentational fix.

and

> You should always bear in mind that the content of a b element may not
>   always be bold, and that of an i element may not always be italic. The
>   actual style is dependent on the CSS style definitions. You should
>   also bear in mind that bold and italic may not be the preferred style
>   for content in certain languages.
>
> You should not use b and i tags if there is a more descriptive and
>   relevant tag available. If you do use them, it is usually better to
>   add class attributes that describe the intended meaning of the markup,
>   so that you can distinguish one use from another.
>
> [The rest of this article will explain this in more detail](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags).

Comment: Su may be right on technical issues that I never objected to but still hasn’t answered my initial question, instead hiding behind the smoke-screen of the HTML5 standard. My initial question, as a reminder, was “But shouldn’t the styling still be preferentially done in the stylesheet rather than the HTML?” Nothing in the documents you or Su linked to suggest otherwise, quite on the contrary.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes the styling should always be done in the stylesheet - the issue you raise is semantics, a html page alone, without the CSS should be readable/usable and that's why using these tags correctly is important.

Comment: It says `<b>` and `<i>` are *not appropriate* for some languages. Unfortunately it doesn't tell me what those languages are.

Comment: @unixman83 I think you would have to know the language well to decide, but certain Asian languages which scan top to bottom may not work with the b and i tags well.

Answer (score 7):

The `b` and `i` tags are not deprecated. (In specs: [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element), [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.1)) What you're concerned with is appropriate use of the tags.

If you're trying to show emphasis in a *meaningful* sense(as now), then you should use `em` or `strong`.

If you just need some text to look *italic*/**bold** as a stylistic choice, then you use `i` or `b`. Consider the logo right here at top of the site, which is effectively "Pro **Webmasters**". The bolding doesn't serve any "meaningful" purpose; you don't even read it with any different emphasis. It's only there so the words are a bit more easily differentiated. (Addendum: As @toomanyairmiles brings up, HTML5 does overload `b` and `i` with [*some* semantic intent](http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/), though it can also occur separately from stylistic use, which isn't exactly my favorite implementation.)

Comment: But shouldn’t the styling still be preferentially done in the stylesheet rather than the HTML? After all, the whole purpose of having separate HTML and CSS was to separate the concerns (contents vs. style). That this separation is imperfect is one thing; to intentionally breach it is quite another.

Comment: I don’t see how this is relevant. The separation is about creating *clean, semantic* content, not about the display in a browser. You may not care about semantic content (which is another point entirely), in which case: knock yourself out. But the HTML5 consortium ostensibly *does* care about this.

Comment: You're right the separation is imperfect, but wrong about the breach. This is baked right into the browsers. Create a plain HTML document with no stylesheet, add some text to it with a few `i` and `b` tags, and open in any browser. What do you see? With the older specs, it's just a simple fact that the elements were there. HTML5 chooses to acknowledge that plain bolding/italic happens enough that practicality *demands* them. In that regard, you should familiarize yourself with the [priority of constituencies](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-design-principles/#priority-of-constituencies).

Comment: You seem to be confusing the order events. HTML5 is actually *based* in part on existing behavior. Elements like `header` exist because it's a near universal pattern to have a "header" in layouts. The same goes for the `b` tag. Again: read the priorities. You're arguing for theoretical purity. That's on the **bottom** of the list.

Comment: You are still conflating two issues. I get that HTML5 acknowledges and stands by the existence of these tags and continues to support them rather than phase them out (which would be unrealistic). Thumbs up for that. *However*, it’s a different thing to then go on and say “so, yeah, they have their place” – because they really don’t, except as a legacy. If you are creating new content, there’s no reason (other than lazyness – it’s shorter to write, after all, and I guess that *is* a valid argument) to prefer `<b>` over a CSS class.

Comment: Your opinion has been noted. It's wrong, but I'm clearly not the person who's going to convince you of that. I'm done here.

Comment: That’s a bit condescending, isn’t it? You are either misrepresenting my argument (unintentionally I guess) or I don’t understand yours. Either way, just brushing it aside as a “wrong opinion” isn’t productive. In particular, I am *not* arguing for theoretical purity in the HTML5 standard. I’m arguing (and you haven’t yet advanced arguments showing this to be wrong) that when *writing* HTML, we can afford the luxury of writing clean code. I’m easily convinced otherwise if you show me that either using those tags *is* clean (i.e. that it has advantages over CSS) or that clean code is unimportant

Comment: Okay, then: citation, please. You're spouting opinions about what you would like to think is true, and how these tags are basically tolerated for legacy rather than actually having a purpose. On the other hand, I've provided a link to where the *spec clearly defines their purpose*. It also has an [entire section for obsolete features](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete)–some of which still conform, which is as close to what you're describing as *actually* exists–from which `b` and `i` are absent. You've not provided a *single* piece of supporting documentation. Now, I'm done.

Comment: Su, the specs explicitly say that “The b and i elements are widely used — it is better to give them good default rendering for various media including aural than to try to ban them.” Which is entirely in line with what I said. Nowhere does the standard recommend them for their usefulness, it merely says that it would be impractical to ban them, which I entirely agree with (and I’ve stated this repeatedly). Nowhere did I suggest that they are (or should be) deprecated.

Comment: I would have to agree with @KonradRudolph. With the dawn of CSS1 (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1-961217#font-weight), the practicality of these tags have been outdated. They haven't deprecated them simply because it's too wide-spread, but given the opportunity I'm sure they would take it.

Comment: Guys chill. They must've fired the dudes who worked for the W3C. **priority of constituencies** proves it!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it's not going against standards to use the `<b>` or `<i>` tags on a website. If you think about it, if a user can't load CSS styles on their browser of choice then how will they differentiate between bold text or italic text without the use of the tags?

I know somewhere that they recommended using `<strong>` tags instead of `<b>` tags, but no where have I seen anyone say `<b>` and `<i>` aren't standards compliant.

Comment: This argument stems primarily from the rhetoric coming from W3C *many years ago* when CSS 1 first came out. W3C then stated that their desire was to eliminate semantic markup from HTML *such as </b>* tags.